# Flutter Raised Button using Focus Node

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working with flutter a menu with several icons, and I would like to leave it highlighted or with a Border side for the applications that are currently selected, but I can't transfer this to the other icons, can you help me?

```
new RaisedButton(
  shape: new CircleBorder(
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepOrange, width: 5)),
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
  onPressed: () {
    _openApp();
  },
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
    child: Image.asset(
      "lib/assets/image/icons/open.png",
      width: 80.0,
      height: 80.0,
    ),
  ),
  elevation: 100.0,
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use highlightColor property of RaisedButton widget. Here how it is done;

```
new RaisedButton(
  shape: new CircleBorder(
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepOrange, width: 5)),
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
  highlightColor: YOUR_PRESSED_COLOR, //Replace with actual colors
  onPressed: () {
    _openApp();
  },
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
    child: Image.asset(
      "lib/assets/image/icons/open.png",
      width: 80.0,
      height: 80.0,
    ),
  ),
  elevation: 100.0,
),
```

Comment: I added or higlightColor, but when the app is selected it doesn't highlight the borders to indicate the app that is selected, so I can't know how to qualify selected at the moment.